# How do I use Regex correctly in this function?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Function nValid(NameVal) As Boolean
    Static NameExpression = New Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")
    Return NameExpression.IsMatch(entryName)
End Function
```

I am using VB for a school project and I'm trying to create a function that will declare, true or false if a name is inputted correctly using the Regex function. When I call it later in my code:

```
       If NameVal = False Then
        MsgBox("This name is incorrect/empty")
```

It comes up as always false. I'm not familiar with the regular expression code but I just wanted to see if anyone here has a clue what I've written wrong.

Comment: Looks to me like you are comparing the value of NameVal to false, are you sure it's not meant to be nValid(NameVal) = false?  Perhaps turn on Option Strict, might give you some more clues

Comment: You're trying to compare a string (`NameVal`) with a boolean (`False`), which will always be false. Why did you write the `nValid` function if you're never going to use it?